# Some URLs cant be connected by cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am making a PHP web crawler using cURL. I can get the content of almost every URL except the URLs belonged to [this website](http://hoanghamobile.com/apple-iphone-6-plus-55-64gb-blackwhitegold-fpt-p1736.html). The browser kept loading and no result is returned. Here is my code

```
    $chs = array();
    $content = array();
    $cmh = curl_multi_init();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
    {
        $chs[$i] = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($chs[$i], CURLOPT_URL, $url_list[$i]);
        curl_setopt($chs[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($chs[$i], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_multi_add_handle($cmh, $chs[$i]);
    }

    $running=null;
    do {
        $status = curl_multi_exec($cmh, $running);
    } while ($running > 0);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
    {
        $content[$i] = curl_multi_getcontent($chs[$i]);
        curl_close($chs[$i]);
    }
    curl_multi_close($cmh);
```

Comment: It is possible that the website is listening for a user-agent but your cURL is not currently providing one.

Comment: Try this `curl` option: `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, smarber thx for your replies. I have added the user agent option but the url still cant be connected. But now the browser stops loading instead of keep running like before...

Comment: Well I think it's possible that the website you are trying to scrape probably has some sort of anti-scrape protection. They might even have a ToS which says that scraping is not allowed...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus well, I have crawled this site successfully by using phpQuery before, but curl just didnt work. That's quite weird...

Comment: What does phpQuery do differently?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus you can take a look at phpQuery at [here](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)... The procedure is the same, fetching content then parse HTML...

Comment: I get the concept. So what does it do **differently**? Does phpQuery not use cURL? If you can't be bothered to read the code then why should anyone else?